# Lvale-to-rvalue conversion of references

Tags: c++, reference, c++14, lvalue

Let's supposed I have an identifier `a` of type `A&`, where `A` is a class type, and the expression `a` is in a context that must be converted to an rvalue. According to the standard (C++14):

> [conv.lval]/1 A glvalue (3.10) of a non-function, non-array type T can
>   be converted to a prvalue. If T is an incomplete type, a program that
>   necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. If T is a non-class type,
>   the type of the prvalue is the cv-unqualified version of T. Otherwise,
>   the type of the prvalue is T.

The glvalue is `a`, and has type `A&`. `A&` is a non-class type, because its type is a reference to class type, so, its cv-unqualified version is `A&`.

If I'm wrong and `A&` is considered a class-type too, despite it is a reference, its prvalue type will be `A&` anyway.

And then,

> [conv.lval]/2 [...] In all other cases, the result of the conversion is determined according to the following rules:
>
> — If T is (possibly cv-qualified) std::nullptr_t, the result is a null pointer constant (4.10).
>
> — Otherwise, if T has a class type, the conversion copy-initializes temporary of type T from the glvalue and the result of the conversion is a prvalue for the temporary.
>
> — Otherwise, if the object to which the glvalue refers contains an invalid pointer value (3.7.4.2, 3.7.4.3), the behavior is implementation-defined.
>
> — Otherwise, the value contained in the object indicated by the glvalue is the prvalue result.

If we say `A&` has class type instead of reference, the conversion should copy-initialize a temporary of type `A&`. If it isn't, the value contained in the `A&` object is the prvalue result, of type `A&` due to the first paragraph.

In any case, `T == A&`. How can a reference be a prvalue? What is what I'm not understanding here?

Comment: [expr]/some-paragraph-whose-number-I-can’t-lookup-on-a-phone. Look for something along the lines of “prior to any further analysis“

Comment: The value of an expression `a` is a glvalue of type `A` (not `A&` - there ain't no such thing as an expression of reference type).

Comment: @T.C. That's it. [expr]/5. It's amazing that from a phone, and thus from memory, you were capable of telling me a phrase with only two ocurrences, and in the same page, in the full standard text.